# How to fix: “No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbname”

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

*Hi, I have this code here, but when the application starts showing me the error! How to fix it? :*

**ERROR :**

> "No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost/database"

**CODE :**

```
try {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://"+host+"/"+database,username,password);
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        System.out.println("Connected to MySQL!");

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Couldn't connect to MySQL!");
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

Comment: What dev environment are you working in?

Comment: Ensure the MySQL JDBC jar is located in the class path.

Comment: Have a look to the right, "Related".

Comment: Check for the driver class first `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");` then get the connection `Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection`

Comment: What are your values for `host` and `database`

Comment: I am using Eclipse SDK, downloading host configuration (it is not important)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure, you have the right version of jar - something like this `mysql-connector-java-5.1.14-bin.jar`

Remember does the host argument includes the port also. (By Default 3306 is the port for MySQL.)

Load the class just like below

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
```

Then it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the MySQL jar(contains the driver class) is in the classpath. To load it before its used actually(may be before try block), you can call

```
Class.forName(<Fully qualified Driver Class name goes here>);
```